# Python Regex for End of Line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex which adds a space before and after a dot.
However I only want this if there is a space or end of line after the dot.

However I am unable to do so for end of line cases.

```
Eg.

I want a hotel. >> I want a hotel .
my email is zob@gmail.com >> my email is zob@gmail.com
I have to play. bye! >> I have to play . bye!
```

Following is my code:

```
# If "Dot and space" after word or number put space before and after
utterance = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z0-9])[.][ $]',' . ',utterance)
```

How do I correct my regex to make sure my 1st example above also works, I tried putting a $ sign in square bracket but that doesn't work.

Comment: You do not want to add a space after the last `.`, right?

Comment: Actually I wouldn't mind eitherway!

Comment: Sorry, did you finally make it work?

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that `$` inside a character class denotes a literal `$` symbol, you just need a [*grouping construct*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) here.

I suggest using the following code:

```
import re
regex = r"([^\W_])\.(?:\s+|$)"
ss = ["I want a hotel.","my email is zob@gmail.com", "I have to play. bye!"]
for s in ss:
    result = re.sub(regex, r"\1 . ", s).rstrip()
    print(result)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/T9Wmav).

If you need to apply this on lines only without affecting line breaks, you can use

```py
import re
regex = r"([^\W_])\.(?:[^\S\n\r]+|$)"
text = "I want a hotel.\nmy email is zob@gmail.com\nI have to play. bye!"
print( re.sub(regex, r"\1 . ", text, flags=re.M).rstrip() )
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/aiNxgb).

Output:

```
I want a hotel . 
my email is zob@gmail.com
I have to play . bye!
```

**Details**:

- `([^\W_])` - Group 1 matching any letter or digit
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `(?:\s+|$)` -  a grouping matching either 1+ whitespaces or end of string anchor (here, `$` matches the end of string.)

The `rstrip` will remove the trailing space added during replacement.

If you are using Python 3, the `[^\W_]` will match all Unicode letters and digits by default. In Python 2, `re.U` flag will enable this behavior.

Note that `\s+` in the last `(?:\s+|$)` will "shrink" multiple whitespaces into 1 space.

Answer (score 2):

Use the lookahead assertion `(?=)` to find a `.` followed by space or end of line `\n`:

```
utterance = re.sub('\\.(?= )|\\.(?=\n)', ' . ', utterance )
```

Answer (score 1):

`[ $]` defines a *class* of characters consisting of a space and a dollar sign, so it matches on space or dollar (literally). To match on space or end of line, use `( |$)` (in this case, `$` keeps it special meaning.